Stripe paymentelement label background color
I am trying to recreate a MUI outlined input, where the label sits on the top border with a background to hide that section of the line.
MUI Example Image
Is it possible to change a stripe input labels background color?  If not, has anyone been able to creatively get the job done?
I tried the stripe appearance api using rules on '.Label'

Edit1:
Sorry, I forgot to mention a couple of things.  I am using Stripe's PaymentElement and believe I need to use the appearance API.
export default function ElementsForm(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <Elements
        stripe={getStripe()}
        options={{
          appearance: {
            labels: 'floating',
            rules: {
              '.Label--floating': {
                marginTop: '-10px',
              },
              '.Input': {
                paddingTop: '0',
                paddingBottom: '0',
                paddingLeft: '15px',
                borderRadius: '25px',
              },
            },
          },
          currency: config.CURRENCY,
          mode: "payment",
          amount: Math.round(config.MAX_AMOUNT / config.AMOUNT_STEP),
        }}
      >
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements >
    </>
  );
}

As you can see the appearance of my code shows the label in the correct position, however, the top border of the input runs through it.
Current Appearance Image

Edit2:
I was able to achieve the desired result with an ugly solution that I came up with using textShadow, but at least it works.
Working Image
Working Code:
export default function ElementsForm(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <Elements
        stripe={getStripe()}
        options={{
          appearance: {
            labels: 'floating',
            rules: {
              '.Label--floating': {
                marginTop: '-10px',
                textShadow: '-5px -1px 0px #fff, -4px -1px 0px #fff, -3px -1px 0px #fff, -2px -1px 0px #fff, -1px -1px 0px #fff, 0px -1px 0px #fff, 1px -1px 0px #fff, 2px -1px 0px #fff, 3px -1px 0px #fff, 4px -1px 0px #fff, 5px -1px 0px #fff, -5px -2px 0px #fff, -4px -2px 0px #fff, -3px -2px 0px #fff, -2px -2px 0px #fff, -1px -2px 0px #fff, 0px -2px 0px #fff, 1px -2px 0px #fff, 2px -2px 0px #fff, 3px -2px 0px #fff, 4px -2px 0px #fff, 5px -2px 0px #fff, -5px -3px 0px #fff, -4px -3px 0px #fff, -3px -3px 0px #fff, -2px -3px 0px #fff, -1px -3px 0px #fff, 0px -3px 0px #fff, 1px -3px 0px #fff, 2px -3px 0px #fff, 3px -3px 0px #fff, 4px -3px 0px #fff, 5px -3px 0px #fff, -5px -4px 0px #fff, -4px -4px 0px #fff, -3px -4px 0px #fff, -2px -4px 0px #fff, -1px -4px 0px #fff, 0px -4px 0px #fff, 1px -4px 0px #fff, 2px -4px 0px #fff, 3px -4px 0px #fff, 4px -4px 0px #fff, 5px -4px 0px #fff, -5px -5px 0px #fff, -4px -5px 0px #fff, -3px -5px 0px #fff, -2px -5px 0px #fff, -1px -5px 0px #fff, 0px -5px 0px #fff, 1px -5px 0px #fff, 2px -5px 0px #fff, 3px -5px 0px #fff, 4px -5px 0px #fff, 5px -5px 0px #fff, -5px 0px 0px #fff, -4px 0px 0px #fff, -3px 0px 0px #fff, -2px 0px 0px #fff, -1px 0px 0px #fff, 0px 0px 0px #fff, 1px 0px 0px #fff, 2px 0px 0px #fff, 3px 0px 0px #fff, 4px 0px 0px #fff, 5px 0px 0px #fff, -5px 1px 0px #fff, -4px 1px 0px #fff, -3px 1px 0px #fff, -2px 1px 0px #fff, -1px 1px 0px #fff, 0px 1px 0px #fff, 1px 1px 0px #fff, 2px 1px 0px #fff, 3px 1px 0px #fff, 4px 1px 0px #fff, 5px 1px 0px #fff, -5px 2px 0px #fff, -4px 2px 0px #fff, -3px 2px 0px #fff, -2px 2px 0px #fff, -1px 2px 0px #fff, 0px 2px 0px #fff, 1px 2px 0px #fff, 2px 2px 0px #fff, 3px 2px 0px #fff, 4px 2px 0px #fff, 5px 2px 0px #fff, -5px 3px 0px #fff, -4px 3px 0px #fff, -3px 3px 0px #fff, -2px 3px 0px #fff, -1px 3px 0px #fff, 0px 3px 0px #fff, 1px 3px 0px #fff, 2px 3px 0px #fff, 3px 3px 0px #fff, 4px 3px 0px #fff, 5px 3px 0px #fff, -5px 4px 0px #fff, -4px 4px 0px #fff, -3px 4px 0px #fff, -2px 4px 0px #fff, -1px 4px 0px #fff, 0px 4px 0px #fff, 1px 4px 0px #fff, 2px 4px 0px #fff, 3px 4px 0px #fff, 4px 4px 0px #fff, 5px 4px 0px #fff, -5px 5px 0px #fff, -4px 5px 0px #fff, -3px 5px 0px #fff, -2px 5px 0px #fff, -1px 5px 0px #fff, 0px 5px 0px #fff, 1px 5px 0px #fff, 2px 5px 0px #fff, 3px 5px 0px #fff, 4px 5px 0px #fff, 5px 5px 0px #fff',
                opacity: '1',
              },
              '.Input': {
                paddingTop: '0',
                paddingBottom: '0',
                paddingLeft: '15px',
                borderRadius: '25px',
              },
            },
          },
          currency: config.CURRENCY,
          mode: "payment",
          amount: Math.round(config.MAX_AMOUNT / config.AMOUNT_STEP),
        }}
      >
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements >
    </>
  );
}


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Did you try a fieldset?

Sorry, I updated the original post

I was able to to achieve the desired result using textShadow as the Stripe appearance API allows that for labels.  It's not my 1st, 2nd, or 3rd choice, but it is the only thing I could get to work.  I wish they would allow backgroundColor for labels.

I was able to achieve the desired result with an ugly solution that I came up with using textShadow, but at least it works.
Working Image
Working Code:
export default function ElementsForm(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <Elements
        stripe={getStripe()}
        options={{
          appearance: {
            labels: 'floating',
            rules: {
              '.Label--floating': {
                marginTop: '-10px',
                textShadow: '-5px -1px 0px #fff, -4px -1px 0px #fff, -3px -1px 0px #fff, -2px -1px 0px #fff, -1px -1px 0px #fff, 0px -1px 0px #fff, 1px -1px 0px #fff, 2px -1px 0px #fff, 3px -1px 0px #fff, 4px -1px 0px #fff, 5px -1px 0px #fff, -5px -2px 0px #fff, -4px -2px 0px #fff, -3px -2px 0px #fff, -2px -2px 0px #fff, -1px -2px 0px #fff, 0px -2px 0px #fff, 1px -2px 0px #fff, 2px -2px 0px #fff, 3px -2px 0px #fff, 4px -2px 0px #fff, 5px -2px 0px #fff, -5px -3px 0px #fff, -4px -3px 0px #fff, -3px -3px 0px #fff, -2px -3px 0px #fff, -1px -3px 0px #fff, 0px -3px 0px #fff, 1px -3px 0px #fff, 2px -3px 0px #fff, 3px -3px 0px #fff, 4px -3px 0px #fff, 5px -3px 0px #fff, -5px -4px 0px #fff, -4px -4px 0px #fff, -3px -4px 0px #fff, -2px -4px 0px #fff, -1px -4px 0px #fff, 0px -4px 0px #fff, 1px -4px 0px #fff, 2px -4px 0px #fff, 3px -4px 0px #fff, 4px -4px 0px #fff, 5px -4px 0px #fff, -5px -5px 0px #fff, -4px -5px 0px #fff, -3px -5px 0px #fff, -2px -5px 0px #fff, -1px -5px 0px #fff, 0px -5px 0px #fff, 1px -5px 0px #fff, 2px -5px 0px #fff, 3px -5px 0px #fff, 4px -5px 0px #fff, 5px -5px 0px #fff, -5px 0px 0px #fff, -4px 0px 0px #fff, -3px 0px 0px #fff, -2px 0px 0px #fff, -1px 0px 0px #fff, 0px 0px 0px #fff, 1px 0px 0px #fff, 2px 0px 0px #fff, 3px 0px 0px #fff, 4px 0px 0px #fff, 5px 0px 0px #fff, -5px 1px 0px #fff, -4px 1px 0px #fff, -3px 1px 0px #fff, -2px 1px 0px #fff, -1px 1px 0px #fff, 0px 1px 0px #fff, 1px 1px 0px #fff, 2px 1px 0px #fff, 3px 1px 0px #fff, 4px 1px 0px #fff, 5px 1px 0px #fff, -5px 2px 0px #fff, -4px 2px 0px #fff, -3px 2px 0px #fff, -2px 2px 0px #fff, -1px 2px 0px #fff, 0px 2px 0px #fff, 1px 2px 0px #fff, 2px 2px 0px #fff, 3px 2px 0px #fff, 4px 2px 0px #fff, 5px 2px 0px #fff, -5px 3px 0px #fff, -4px 3px 0px #fff, -3px 3px 0px #fff, -2px 3px 0px #fff, -1px 3px 0px #fff, 0px 3px 0px #fff, 1px 3px 0px #fff, 2px 3px 0px #fff, 3px 3px 0px #fff, 4px 3px 0px #fff, 5px 3px 0px #fff, -5px 4px 0px #fff, -4px 4px 0px #fff, -3px 4px 0px #fff, -2px 4px 0px #fff, -1px 4px 0px #fff, 0px 4px 0px #fff, 1px 4px 0px #fff, 2px 4px 0px #fff, 3px 4px 0px #fff, 4px 4px 0px #fff, 5px 4px 0px #fff, -5px 5px 0px #fff, -4px 5px 0px #fff, -3px 5px 0px #fff, -2px 5px 0px #fff, -1px 5px 0px #fff, 0px 5px 0px #fff, 1px 5px 0px #fff, 2px 5px 0px #fff, 3px 5px 0px #fff, 4px 5px 0px #fff, 5px 5px 0px #fff',
                opacity: '1',
              },
              '.Input': {
                paddingTop: '0',
                paddingBottom: '0',
                paddingLeft: '15px',
                borderRadius: '25px',
              },
            },
          },
          currency: config.CURRENCY,
          mode: "payment",
          amount: Math.round(config.MAX_AMOUNT / config.AMOUNT_STEP),
        }}
      >
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements >
    </>
  );
}

